# Meteor Collections as static members of Coffeescript class

Tags: mongodb, meteor, coffeescript

OK. I thought that this would be a good idea for structuralizing my next Meteor application. I use Coffeescript/Jade/Stylus stack with Meteor.

My idea is to do something like this:

```
class @Lorem
  @collection = new Mongo.Collection('lorem_ipsum')
  constructor: (@a, @b, @c, @d, @e) ->
```

So that I could do either this `lorem = new Lorem` for creating structurized objects or just `Lorem.collection.find({})` for direct Mongo access. Of course I want to create a layer of methods like:

```
lorem = new Lorem
lorem.add() # for adding to collection
lorem.remove() # for removing from collection
# etc.
```

I already got the collection working I can do something like this:

```
Lorem.collection.insert({a: 'test', b: 'test'}) # just an example, schemas would come later on
```

Is it a viable structure for code? Are there any better ways to properly structurize data and objects in Meteor (Coffeescript)?

Comment: I think it's an interesting approach, but not appropriate for stackoverflow because it's entirely opinion-based. You may want to have a look at [astronomy](https://github.com/jagi/meteor-astronomy) which implements something similar. For a discussion of this type of approach, see [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/guide/issues/10) on the [meteor guide](https://github.com/meteor/guide).

Comment: Thank you for those links especially astronomy! It looks kinda like what I wanted to build! And true, I'll try to avoid asking opinion-based/subjective questions next time.